# Defining a class templates constructor and providing the template arguments

Tags: c++

C++ does not seem to care if I provide the constructor of a class template with template arguments or not. Here is an example:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  Foo() { /* ... */ } // OK
  Foo<T> { /* ... */ } // Also OK
}
```

Is there a difference between these two constructor definitions? Also, while on the topic of providing template arguments, why don't you have to provide the arguments to a class template parameter when the declaration is inside of the same class? Example below:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  Foo(const Foo& other) { /* ... */ } // OK
  Foo(const Foo<T>& other) { /* ... */ } // Also OK
  void Foobar(const Foo& foo) { /* ... */ } // Still OK
};

// Somewhere outside Foo...
void Foobar(const Foo& foo) { /* ... */ } // Not OK
```

Does this have something to do with it being part of the current instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every class has an *injected class name*, which is a member typedef that refers to the class itself. For a non-template class `Foo`, the injected class name is also `Foo`. For `Foo<T>` (a specialization of class template `Foo`), the injected class name is `Foo` (that is, without the template arguments). Therefore, within class `Foo<T>`, the names `Foo` and `Foo<T>` can both be used to refer to the class `Foo<T>` itself.

Comment: Can this be accessed outside the class if I for some reason want to? For example, would `typename vector<int>::vector v;` make a variable `v` with type `vector<int>` or a compiler error complaining `vector<int>` has no member type `vector`?

Comment: @DanielH Yes, it can be used outside the class, but your particular example won't work because the lookup will find the constructor rather than the injected class name.

Comment: Since all classes have constructors, in what circumstance could it be used without finding the constructor instead?

Comment: @DanielH For example, `struct S : std::vector<int>::vector {};`. When looking up a name in a base-specifier, constructors and other function names are ignored.